# How to inspect a container's IP, obtain it and add it to /etc/hosts file with a local domain name resolution

Tags: docker, dns, containers, local, hosts

I am working on Linux Ubuntu with docker containers and I want the following added to the last line of /etc/hosts in a new line:

IP_from_docker_container     hostname_assigned
172.20.1.2                   docker.dev.example.com

I have been trying commands such as: *echo, printf, aux, sed, tee*

**This is what i unsuccessfully tried:**

```
echo "\n" | docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' CONTAINER | echo "       docker.dev.whip-around.com" | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts
```

**Command to get container's IP works fine. I put it here as a reference only:**

```
 docker inspect -f '{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' CONTAINER_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

`>>` appends to a file, so you can try this:

```
echo `docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' CONT_NAME` example.com >> /etc/hosts
```

Comment: nope permission denied. It works if you do this:   
> echo `docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' CONT_NAME` example.com | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts

Comment: or... just add sudo at the beginning?

Comment: sorry i take commands very literally. yes sudoing of course works